# What do I need to consider when I develop python code for Linux AND Windows?

Tags: python, linux, windows

I want to create python (2.7) code to work under Linux and Windows. What do I have to consider especially? What are the differences I need to take care of? Is there a summary available somewhere listing the possible pitfalls?

Comment: This is a good topic for discussion, e.g. [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). Not so much for Q&A format of the SO main page.

Comment: Expanding on Fenikso's point. SO main page works on the premise that users ask a concise and specific question, explain what they want to do and what they've tried. We tend to deal with code directly and sometimes theory, but always in a specific context. Questions like this, to me, fall under the "How do I learn python" context which tends not to go down too well here. Try asking this question in a place where open discussion is welcomed, not a strict Q&A platform.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Pariah's answers:  make sure the #! line is there, it is fairly easy to write a python program to insert it.  Equally, it makes life easier if you use something like `dos2unix` to remove the "\r" from line endings.  Personally the program I have to add the #! line deals with line ends, and does a `chmod` for good measure.

On Windows it is worth remembering that / is a valid directory separator in path names, so that can be used, however using `os.path.join` is safer.  Generally, try to avoid hard-coding paths.

File IO as text on Windows will insert (write) or remove (read) the '\r', so random access should use binary (open mode as 'wb' or 'rb').

Environment variables (if you use them) are not case sensitive on Windows, but are on Linux.

Try to keep the Python versions the same.  You won't necessarily get issues if you don't, but it does rule one suspect out when you find a program works on one but fails on the other.  Also, if one is 64-bit then make sure the other is as well.  This should be invisible to most Python code, but you need to rule out as many differences as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have been of late developing code in 2.7 (Python) on windows and i plan to transfer it on to a raspberry pi embedded system (which uses a linux distro).

The things i keep in mind during the move over:

1. Libraries very important to know what is supported on both windows and linux distro's
2. Permissions also very important because windows users are by default admin whereas linux needs sudo or higher privileges that normally can’t be accessed.
3. Directories, if you list any directories in windows and simply copy over the code, that access will have a very high chance of failing.

Comment: Gotta figure out what im doing wrong to get upvotes to make my life easier :P